# Express serve 2 different Angular PWAs

Tags: node.js, angular, express, web-hosting, progressive-web-apps

I have been struggling with it for some time, and I am starting to think that my approach is wrong altogether. If this is a case please let me know and provide some direction.

### Context

I have two angular applications, one regular (for desktop), and one ionic (for mobile devices). I serve them using express server like that:

```js
app.use(expressStatic(path.join(__dirname, '/../web-app'), { index: false }));
app.use(expressStatic(path.join(__dirname, '/../ionic-app'), { index: false }));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  if (isMobile(req)) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/../ionic-app/index.html'));
  } else {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/../web-app/index.html'));
  }
});
```

It worked file but I have recently made them (both) PWAs using `ng add @angular/pwa ...` command, and did not change anything related to service worker there.

### Problem

Now I have noticed one problem with that solution. Should those two locations `/../web-app` `/../ionic-app` have a file named the same (eg. `ngsw-worker.js`, `manifest.webmanifest`) one would be omitted when requested like that `<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest">`. I am not sure which one would be served.

#### Solving problem of files with the same names

I have tried to walk around the problem by replacing the above code with:

```js
app.get('*.*', (req, res, next) => {
  if (isMobile(req)) {
    expressStatic(path.join(__dirname, '/../ionic-app'))(req, res, next);
  } else {
    expressStatic(path.join(__dirname, '/../web-app'))(req, res, next);
  }
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  if (isMobile(req)) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/../ionic-app/index.html'));
  } else {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/../web-app/index.html'));
  }
});
```

That solved the problem of files being "overwritten" but I have found at least one more problem. Following those steps:

1. Enter site in mobile mode - it works ✅
2. Try to enter with network off (offline) - it works ✅
3. Request desktop version of the site - it works ✅
4. Try to enter with network off (offline) - it does not work ❌
5. Go back to mobile version of the site - it works ✅
6. Try to enter with network off (offline) - it does not work ❌

I know this is a scenario that does not apply to the most users but still would like it to work. Moreover that it kills ability to run app offline until someone clears cache.

I am also afraid this is solution is not very "clean", or "by the book".

### Question

What would be the "go to", "elegant" solution for serving two different version of the app depending on the device (desktop/mobile)?

I would prefer to keep the solution as simple as possible, firebase or heroku for hosting, so no complex nginx solutions, etc.

### My thoughts/Research

I have noticed varying behaviour on the internet:

- facebook, and some older websites redirect you to a different path with a mobile app (`facebook.com` -> `m.facebook.com`) - this is not a solution I have in mind.
- airbnb does it silently, sort of how I want it here. So that url is the same but the app served is different.

Comment: Between steps 4 and 5, did you turn the network on? I think that your service worker it's download only the first version that loads.

Comment: @GabrielLopes Step 4 is turning off network, or at least simulating it. Still I think the rest of what service worker does works correctly - resources seem to be served through a service worker.